# Ajax Request - Use last array

Tags: jquery, ajax

i use this following Code:

```
        var old_count = <?php echo $_SESSION["technic"] ?>;

    function repeatMe(){
     $.ajax({
      url: 'live_notifications/technic_open.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: true,
      success: function(data) {

              if (data > old_count) {

        $.notification({
            title: 'Headline',
            content: 'Test '+ data[5].art +'',
            showTime: true,
            error: true, 
            icon: 'X'
            });

        }

                old_count = data;
        }
     });
    }

    setInterval(repeatMe, 1000);
```

This works so far, but data[5] must be dynamic. The digit mus be the last digit in my database.

For example:

10 Database Entries = data[10]

30 Database Entries = data[30]

and so on. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if data is array use `data[data.length-1]` to get last index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the last cell in "data" array, you can use: `data[data.length-1]`